# How to clone webforms?

Tags: webform-civicrm

They are various drupal modules that allow to clone a webform, but so far, all the ones I tried didn't play nicely with webform_civicrm and introduced weird problems.

Do you have one that you use and that works when your form is connected to civicrm?

Answer (score 5):

I previously had problems with node_clone (you had to enable civicrm option in cloned node), but last few projects it seemed to work properly.

What are the weird problems?

Comment: node_clone always worked fine for me.

Comment: Agreed, node_clone has worked for us.

Comment: yep ditto, or is that tritto

Comment: Use node_clone on every site with webforms, never had an issue

Comment: Anyone got a working solution for Drupal 9?